# Free e-signature in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, digital-signature

How Can I add Signature on contact form ? does anyone know any signature plugin on wordpress that is FREE.

I have already tried `contact form 7` but I'm having a hard time integrating with `send pdf with contact form 7`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Contact Form 7 add-ons available.
1. Contact Form 7 Signature Addon [signature Addon](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-signature-addon/)

2. Contact Forms 7 Digital Signature Add-on [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/digital-signature-contact-form-7-addon/)

I have used same as per your requirement. If any issue let me know.

Comment: Hi manisha, 

1.) I've tried contact form 7 signature addon but everytime I add signature to my form it gives me an error. 

2.) Is this the only plugin that I have to download? Is it free?

Comment: Manisha - Contact Forms 7 Digital Signature Add-on requires me to download additional plugins, which unfortunately isn't free

Comment: Hii,  I have used https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-signature-addon/. And This plugin is integrated with Contact form 7.  And which error you face?

Comment: Hi Manisha, sorry for the late response. I can't submit my form whenever I add the signature plugin

Comment: Please check CSS. What blocking for submission of Form? Check overflow=hidden anywhere? Please share me link if possible.

Comment: Hi Manisha, it gives me a status of 403. I ddn't add any element just the signature and submit button

Comment: It works if I spam click the submit button but it sends too many requests

Comment: Also, how do I change the timezone for the time and date shortcodes?

Comment: For Wordpress you can change timezone from setting. Provide me link if it's on live server.

Comment: could you help me find a workaround why it isn't submitting? thank you so much

Comment: Apply Clearfix class after every row. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp .

clearfix {
    clear: both;
} 
There are some issue related to CSS. Try after make All other plugin deactivated.

Comment: Did you try my test site?

Comment: If it's your test site then can you provide me temporary login detail. So, I can check Properly. If I Can do something.

Comment: I can't... as I'm not the only one working on the site. Can't you debug it without loggin in the admin panel? I can submit the form but it gives me access denied..

Comment: Write a code in new form:

<div class="myform" >
<div class="row">
<label> Your Name (required)
    [text* your-name] </label>
</div>
<div class="row">
[signature* signature-185 id:sign class:sign]
</div>
[submit "Send"]

</div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164002/discussion-between-rj-tubera-and-manisha-vasani).